# How can I use the Windows version of NGROK from behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: node.js, twilio, ngrok

How can I use the Windows version of NGROK from behind a corporate proxy?

I am using [Node JS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install) and I need to reach out api.twilio.com.

Example:

```
// Twilio Credentials 
var accountSid = 'ACCOUNTSID'; 
var authToken = 'AUTHTOKEN'; 


//require the Twilio module and create a REST client
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

client.messages.create({ 
    to: "+16518675309", 
    from: "+14158141829", 
    body: "Thanks for the help StackOverflow!", 
    mediaUrl: "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg",  
}, function(err, message) { 
    console.log(message.sid); 
});
```

Comment: That's not what ngrok does. ngrok allows other people to connect to you, not the other way around. If you need to talk to `api.twilio.com` for work purposes I would talk to your manager or whoever meanages the firewall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out the [ngrok FAQ](https://ngrok.com/faq)?  The first item may answer your question:

*Does ngrok work behind an HTTP Proxy?*

*Yes. You may specify an HTTP proxy to connect through in ngrok's configuration file or by using the standard unix environment variable http_proxy. Consult the documentation on running ngrok through an HTTP proxy for more details.*